# Cross domain request timeout in IE11 only (fine in other browsers)

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11, http-status-code-504

I have an issue with an app running in Internet Explorer 11 which makes an external API request to amplitude.com and returns an 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT error - this causes a long delay in the page (it will sometimes crash) and returns the following in the console.

```
SEC7120: Origin https://live.mysite.com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
live.mysite.com

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.
live.mysite.com
```

When looking at the network tab I can see that this request has posted
When loading the same site in Chrome/Firefox it works perfectly fine (no delay issues)

When trying the same in Microsoft Edge it appears to work fine - any ideas why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, I hope you've found a fix.

Got the same issue today! I was making a cross domain request using http that was automatically redirected by the server to https. Doing the ajax request using https fixed my issue. It seems that IE can't handle http to https redirection and says its a 504 ... I don't know why.